# vagrant error:Vagrantfile already exists in this directory

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualbox, vagrant, virtualization

When I input `$ vagrant box list`,
Terminal outputs: `centos64 (virtualbox)`

Now I input `$ vagrant init centos64`,
Terminal outputs an error message:

```
"Vagrantfile" already exists in this directory. Remove it before running "vagrant init".
```

How do I remove it?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can remove the Vagrantfile by typing `rm Vagrantfile`
at the command line, but it is not clear what you are trying to achieve.

The `vagrant init` command will initialise a new virtual box by creating a default Vagrantfile. Since you already have one, it looks like you may already have run the `vagrant init` command.

If you are trying to start the VM then you need to use the command `vagrant up centos64`

Answer (score 6):

From website : https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/cli/init.html

To overwrite any existing Vagrantfile use :

vagrant init {BOX_NAME} --force

If specified, this command will overwite any existing Vagrantfile.

and then

vagrant up

Answer (score 0):

You just deleted the VMinstance.
so just put 

`vagrant up`

and the instance comes up and run.

Answer (score 0):

If you are having any difficulty initializing a file on vagrant, simply overwrite the file.
e.g the name of the file is ubuntu/focal64

To remove:

```
rm vagrantfile ubuntu/focal64
```

To overwrite:

```
vagrant init ubuntu/focal64 --force
```

If removing is giving issues, simply overwrite it.